# elementor showing notice in website: undefined index options

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm not sure because of what but it's showing a notice message. by looking at it I believe this message is because of Elementor and its module theme builder widgets. I don't work with Elementor, so I'm not sure what went wrong or the possible solution to this.
[image: this is the warning showing at header on every page]

can you please help?

Comment: looks like elementor pro either need an update, or you need to press the "elementor need to update the database" button. - had this error a few days ago, when I was updating my plugins - After I pressed the button, the warning dissappeared

Answer (score 0):

The notice specifically is not necessarily a problem to be concerned with. It is a notice, not an error. If it said error, it would be a problem. This notice is output to let Elementor developers know that something about their code, though not wrong, could be improved. This output occurs when debugging is enabled on the WordPress site. Ideally, plugin developers release versions that debug cleanly, but it's more difficult with larger plugins such as Elementor.

It may be an issue if you're outputting debugging messages on a production website though. This can expose important information about your server to anyone that comes across it including hackers. Debugging mode should only be enabled on development sites. If necessary to debug a production site you should only output to log file and not display and then disable when finished debugging so your log file doesn't explode.

To disable debugging on the site, edit the site's wp-config.php file to define the debugging constants and values.

```
// WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

// Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', false );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: That's not a solution but a quick work around. Thanks